# Getting controller name from array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There must be a smarter way to do what I'm doing here.

I'm in the show page for a model of mine in a rails project. That model is Vehicle.

Each Vehicle has_many mileage records so I'm trying to display those on the show page of each Vehicle.

I'm rendering a partial 'records_table' (so I can reuse it for service records further down the page). The problem is that in that partial I'm rendering the table headers using the following code:

```
<%= render "table_headers" %>
```

That renders the table_headers for Vehicle, not for a Mileage Record (for obvious reasons). I can work around the problem by doing this to get the name of the views folder (the name of the controller associated with mileage records)

```
<%= render "#{objs.first.class.name.pluralize.underscore}/table_headers" %>
```

That's such an ugly way to do things. Is there another way to get the name of the controller from an array of objects (assuming they're all from the same model)? Or is there a better way to designate which table_headers I want (without just statically typing mileage_records as this needs to accomodate for other types of records)?

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a variable to the partial, as described here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

in section 3.4.4?

You can pass controller.controller_name to the _records partial, which could then reference a hash or lookup table elsewhere to determine which records it should show.